# Disable On-Screen-Keyboard

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, on-screen-keyboard

I'm developing a Windows Store app for an embedded application where the only input device is a small touchscreen. For this reason I'm developing my own number and text entry controls that match the visual look of the application and work better on the small screen. Is it possible to prevent the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard from appearing when a textbox gets focus?

Comment: Have you tried this idea/hack? http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2013/05/close-winrt-virtual-keyboard-programatically/  (Honestly, Microsoft wants you to use the built-in keyboards for a consistent experience across applications, and when the keyboards improve in the OS, as they do in Win 8.1, your app will benefit.)

Comment: I agree that UI fragmentation isn't desirable, however in this specific application the App is going to run in Kiosk mode and hide the Windows interface completely from the user. The entire GUI is customised, the only reason I'm creating it as a Windows Store app as opposed to WPF is that a lot of the complex multi-touch controls I need already exist there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, it's a user preference as of now.

Similar question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571065/is-it-possible-in-c-sharp-to-show-hide-and-manipulate-the-windows-8-on-screen)

From Hanselman

> Unfortunately there is no checkbox or "just turn it off" way to
>   disable the keyboard with a supported option.
>   However, there is a way to effectively disable the keyboard by
>   stopping the service that controls it.
>
> Press the Windows key + W Type "services," and press Enter Scroll down
>   to "Touch screen keyboard and handwriting panel" You can either right
>   click and "Stop" or you can double-click and change it from
>   "Automatic" startup to "Manual."

Comment: That sorts it. Thanks!