# Stop Windows 8 keyboard displaying when entering textbox in windows 8 store application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I've designed a Windows 8 store application to use a custom keyboard for my input as the built-in keyboard didn't match my requirements.

So is there anyway to stop the built in keyboard displaying when a textbox is entered?

I can do this via services in windows but I still need the built in keyboard for use in Windows itself. So I need to stop the keyboard appearing in the application. Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745090/disable-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: Are you sure that input scopes didn't fit your needs?

Comment: I think you can use some element looks like textbox. for example, textblock in a border with borderbrush, when tapped it, your custom keyboard display, and when your keyboard keys tapped. textblock display the text.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. try this.

When the textbox that showed the virtual keyboard has it’s property IsEnabled set to false, the virtual keyboard disappears. We can immediately set is to true after that and the virtual keyboard will remain hidden. Just like this:

```
MyTextBox.KeyDown += (s, a) => {
    if (a.Key == VirtualKey.Enter) {
        MyTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
        MyTextBox.IsEnabled = true;
    }
};
```