# Disable onscreen keyboard using

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a windows form in which I have a numeric keyboard. when user click on the `text box` my numeric keyboard appears.but the problem is I moved my application to a touch screen keyboard. when user clicks on my `text box` default touch screen keyboard appears.

Is there any possibility to close the touch screen keyboard on my application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's a user preference as of now.

Similar question is found here

[Is it possible in c# to show, hide, and manipulate the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571065/is-it-possible-in-c-sharp-to-show-hide-and-manipulate-the-windows-8-on-screen)

Please refer 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/17d2486f-abbb-4352-9aaf-5a457128678a/touch-keyboard?forum=winappswithcsharp