# Xamarin Forms - Prevent Keyboard from Showing on Entry Focus in UWP, Android, iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, keyboard, xamarin.uwp

In Xamarin.Forms, I can prevent keyboard from popping up when Entry view receives focus by creating custom renderers and using ShowSoftInputOnFocus for Android and InputView for iOS.

But what can I use to prevent it in UWP?

Comment: Hi @cd491415 have you found any solution to prevent the soft keyboard popping up on entry focus for xamarin forms uwp?

Answer (score 1):

> prevent keyboard from popping up when Entry view receives focus

UWP has direct API support to hide and show the [InputPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane). You could invoke `TryHide` method to hide keyboard. For xamarin you could use `DependencyService` to approach. For more please refer the following code.

**Interface**

```
public interface IKeyboard
{
    void HideKeyboard();
    void ShowKeyboard();
    void RegisterAction(Action<object, KeyboardState> callback);
}
public enum KeyboardState
{
    Hide,
    Show
}
```

**KeyboardImplementation.cs**

```
public class KeyboardImplementation : IKeyboard
{
    private InputPane _inputPane;
    private Action<object, KeyboardState> action;

    public KeyboardImplementation()
    {
        _inputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
        _inputPane.Showing += OnInputPaneShowing;
        _inputPane.Hiding += OnInputPaneHiding;
    }
    public void HideKeyboard()
    {
        _inputPane.TryHide();
    }
    public void ShowKeyboard()
    {
        _inputPane.TryShow();
    }
    public void RegisterAction(Action<object, KeyboardState> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    private void OnInputPaneHiding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
    {
        action(this, KeyboardState.Hide);
    }

    private void OnInputPaneShowing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
    {
        action(this, KeyboardState.Show);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
DependencyService.Get<IKeyboard>().RegisterAction((s,e)=> {
    if (e == KeyboardState.Show)
    {
        var keyboard = s as IKeyboard;
        keyboard.HideKeyboard();
    }
});
```

Comment: @NicoShu Thanks Nico but this solution will show soft keyboard then hide it.  I am looking for a solution to not show keyboard at all when Entry receives focus.  I have found article explaining how to do that using custom entry renderer and ShowSoftInputOnFocus for Android and InputView on iOS but custom renderers do same, keyboard will still show up briefly, then go away.  Same is which your suggestion which makes things even worse since user now keeps getting keyboard pop up then disappear by itself.

Comment: Yep, this solution is just used to hide keyboard and it is global setting. it could be flexible with  making unsubscribe method in the interface. And there is another solution in uwp, please refer this [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39517700/7254781). if you think it is feasible, I could help make a plugin for xamarin `Entry` control.

Comment: Thanks @NicoShu but I am not looking for solution to hide keyboard.  I am looking for solution to ***prevent*** keyboard from showing up entirely once custom Entry receives focus.  Popping keyboard and then hiding it makes it even worse.

Comment: Yep, I know, but currently, there is no such property for xaml control. if you do want this feature, please feel free post it in [user voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: The link you provided has no area to request feature for Xamarin Forms at all??

Comment: Because your requirement part is  in uwp, so the above link is microsoft uservioce. For xamarin forms you could post your  requirement in [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: I think this solution unavoidably leads to spaghetti code because next thinkg that will happen, you will have calls to Focus, HideKeyboard, Showkeyboard all over the code competing with each other.  For a hello world, yes this will show keyboard then hide it and I guess that *smell* if good for you, will work.  But it is obvious hack, your competition will come to you and say "hey, how come other guy's app does not pop the keyboard and hide it all the time???  It is ridiculous to have to do such hacks all over the Xamarin.  If you find solution for this working on all 3 platforms please share