# How Prevent soft keyboard from showing on Entry focus - xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer, soft-keyboard, xamarin.forms.entry

I am using an custom entry that will shows a popup when Entry focused, so there is no need of soft keyboard, as of now **the keyboard just popping up on the screen and then hiding**.

**How to prevent the soft keyboard without event showing up when Entry focused?**

I have gone through same scenario like me that also still pending and unanswered, please share any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Please check the following like for reference
[Prevent soft keyboard in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439208/xamarin-forms-prevent-keyboard-from-showing-on-entry-focus-in-uwp-android-io)

Comment: Hi bro, have you solved this problem ? Here is a good discussion , may be helpful to refer.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5cf56948-7f3c-44d5-a5a9-070a97424e2a/uwpshow-touch-keyboard?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thanks @JuniorJiang-MSFT, i have used the Label to replace Entry since its just have to open popup when Entry focused.

Comment: Great, glad you find the solution :)

Comment: Have you been able to prevent keyboard from popping up?  How did you do it?  I am having same issue in Xamarin.Forms and would like not to show soft keyboard when a specific Entry is focused.

Comment: @pixel, as i said in earlier comment, I have replaced the Entry to Label that looks exactly look as an Entry (in my scenario there is no need to enter from keyboard).

Comment: @Ryas Could you provide your solution with label?  How do you Focus on a label?  How do you trigger a command or event when you finish entering text in a Label to process it?

Comment: @pixel actually in my scenario, when you focus the label an popup(numeric keyboard look a like) there you can enter the values and click ok then those values binded to the Label in the page. What do you want exactly, ill give solution if i can.

Comment: @Riyas So no keyboard pops up but your customized version of some sort of numeric keys are displayed by your code?  Also, how do you focus on the label?  Do you do it from code using Focus() call or?

Comment: Using TapGestrureRecogniser command.