# Handle close button on Windows Keyboard WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on a WPF application and I run into a problem.
I would like to disable the Windows Keyboard Close button. In my case, I have a button that opens the keyboard which should remain opened until the user presses another button. In this scenario I have to restrict the user from closing the keyboard.

Here is the X button that I want to handle/disable:
[image]

`KeyDown` event is not raised when pressing X button. Any ideas?

Comment: It`s windows 8 to 10 keyboard

Comment: I don't think it's possible, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571065/is-it-possible-in-c-sharp-to-show-hide-and-manipulate-the-windows-8-on-screen).

Comment: To disable the close button, I think is almost impossible. But in order to handle somehow the X button, should be something, right? maybe an event... I don't know :(